# “! Argument of \xpg@nospace has an extra }” error message with polyglossia

Tags: xetex, luatex, polyglossia, soul

I use a code – to be found at the end – for long citations in the french tradition. When I use french quotation marks inside such a long citation, I have no problem on compiling with `xetex` if I load `babel` with the french option, and the error message

> Argument of \xpg@nospace has an extra }.

when loading `polyglossia`. The same happens on compiling with `lualatex,` though with a different error message, beginning with

> Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed.

The problem disappears if I define in the preamble of the document :

```
\newcommand*{\og}{«{}} \newcommand*{\fg}{{}»}
```

and if the french quotation marks inside the long citation are replaced by `\og` … `\fg`.

So I suspect there is some conflict between `polyglossia` and `soul` – or my way of using `soul`. I first posted on fr.comp.text.tex, but obtained no solution.

Best regards,
 B. Alfonsi

Code (and minimal example):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, twoside]{article} 

\usepackage{fontspec}% f 
 \setmainfont{Minion Pro}% 
 %\usepackage[french]{babel} 
 \usepackage{polyglossia} 
 \setmainlanguage{french} 

\usepackage{soulutf8} 
 \usepackage {kvsetkeys} 
 \makeatletter 
 \newsavebox \citeguill@box 
 \define@key {citeguill}{left}[\guillemotleft]{\def\citeguill@left {#1}} 
 \define@key {citeguill}{right}[\guillemotright]{\def\citeguill@right {#1}} 
 \define@key {citeguill}{middle}[\hskip -\fontdimen2\font\mbox \guillemotright\hskip\fontdimen2\font]{\def\citeguill@middle 
 {\setbox\citeguill@box =\hbox {#1}\def\citeguill@middle {\copy 
 \citeguill@box }}% 
 }% \KV@citeguill@middle 
 \newcommand*\citeguillsetup [1]{\def\citeguill@setup {\kvsetkeys 
 {citeguill}{#1}}} 
 \let\citeguill@setup =\relax % 

\newcommand*\citeguill [1][]{% 
 \kvsetkeys{citeguill}{left,right,middle}\citeguill@setup% 
 \kvsetkeys{citeguill}{#1}% 
 \SOUL@setup% 
 \def\SOUL@preamble {\citeguill@middle \citeguill@left }% 
 \def\SOUL@postamble {\citeguill@right }% 
 \def\SOUL@everysyllable {\the\SOUL@syllable }% 
 \def\SOUL@everyspace ##1{##1\nobreak \ 
 \discretionary {\kern-\fontdimen 2\font } 
 {\citeguill@middle } 
 {}}% 
 \def\SOUL@everyhyphen {\discretionary% 
 {\SOUL@setkern \SOUL@hyphkern \SOUL@sethyphenchar } 
 {\citeguill@middle } 
 {}}% 
 \def\SOUL@everyexhyphen ##1{\SOUL@setkern \SOUL@hyphkern 
 \hbox{##1}\discretionary {} 
 {\citeguill@middle } 
 {\SOUL@setkern \SOUL@charkern }}% 
 \SOUL@% 
 }% \citeguill 
 \makeatother 

\begin{document} 

Pour conclure, les rédacteurs de \emph{L’Anti-Mythes} résument bien la question BHL 
telle qu’elle se pose à l’automne 1977 : \citeguill{Que le cynisme séduise, que la 
bêtise paie et que la mode soit au renouveau des idées les plus réactionnaires, cela 
ne suffit pas à expliquer l’extraordinaire exploitation par les médias du phénomène 
«nouveaux philosophes», ni leur impressionnant succès commercial.} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Bernard. :-)

Comment: There's no problem if I use `babel`; there's nothing wrong in using `babel` with XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an incompatibility between the workings of `soul` and how the `\XeTeXinterchartoks` feature is implemented in Polyglossia for French, regarding the guillemets.

If I say at the end of the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\appto\blockextras@french{%
  \XeTeXinterchartoks \french@punctguillstart 4095 = {\nobreakspace\ignorespaces}%
}
\appto\inlineextras@french{%
  \XeTeXinterchartoks \french@punctguillstart 4095 = {\nobreakspace\ignorespaces}%
}
\makeatother
```

(basically using `babel`'s 3.9 definition), the error disappears. Polyglossia uses there `\xpg@nospace` that reads an argument, which is probably what confuses `soul`.

Of course this doesn't work with LuaLaTeX, for which you need `babel`. However, my advice is to use `babel` anyway, there's nothing wrong with it, particularly now that version 3.9 introduces XeLaTeX support.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! It works perfectly. The problem with babel is that I use MiKTeX 2.9, and it has only babel 3.8 up to now. What I do not understand, though, is why the same problem happens with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Bernard You get other errors with LuaLaTeX and Polyglossia, I believe

Comment: Yes – at least other messages. However in both cases, if I force compilation the resulting pdf is normal.

Comment: Note that the word boundary class currently has the number 4095 (since 2016) instead of 255.

Comment: @Marijn Yes, thanks for noting.